# Changed alternator bought new battery will not start

Tags: battery, alternator

Got a new battery it would start. But auto zone told me alternator was bad. Changed it now i have nothing no crank or start. Hooked it all back up like it was

Comment: What vehicle are you working on? Make/model/engine/year?

Answer (score 1):

Recheck the wires that connect the battery and the alternator.

Do you get power anywhere else in the car? Lights? When you turn the key?

Your new battery could be bad. If so, you could try jumping the car, and it should keep running if the alternator is good. If it starts but doesnt keep running when you disconnect everything, then alternator is bad. If it doesnt start with jump, then ur jumping it wrong or maybe ur starter is dead.